# How do I add a submission handler to the contact form?

Tags: 8, emails

I am trying to get a value from the query string and process it with contact form values to send in email.

For example, I have a contact form with different fields. I want to load one node information (title, description, prize, and PDF) and attach the PDF file to the email sent with the contact form.

How do I add a form submission handler to the contact form?

Comment: Use hook_mail_alter.